# ImageJ concatenate macro runs alone but get error: "filename" is not a valid choice for "image1" in larger macro

Tags: concatenation, imagej

I am analyzing hyperstacks of MRI images that are off-resonance and need to be compiled into a single stack of on-resonance images. I need to manually do part of this, so I tell the program how many substacks I need, and I specify the slice #'s. Then, based on the direction of my sample (which I also input: big to small taper (B-S) or small to big taper (S-B)), the images need to concatenate for that direction. I would ideally like to figure out how to make a loop so the concatenation will work for any number of substacks that I may have, but I don't even know how to go about that at this stage.

I've tried "+" around the name, []'s, ()'s, ""'s, & before the specific substack names, trying to use selectWindow...other things I've forgotten...

```
    //SPECIFIES NUMBER OF STACKS TO MAKE AND LOOPS
    numberofstacks=getNumber("How many stacks?", 3);
       i=0;
       do {
    selectWindow("2D"); 
    first=getNumber("Enter first slice:", 0);
    last=getNumber("Enter last slice:", 0);
    run("Make Substack...", "  slices="+first+"-"+last);
    getInfo("image.filename");
    rename("substack"+i);
    i=i+1;
    }while (i<numberofstacks);
   //INSERTS PAUSE FOR USER TO ADJUST CONTRAST IN STACKS
   waitForUser("Press OK to continue");
   //MAKES INPUT TO DECIDE IF CODING S-B or B-S
   bs=getString("Scrolling from left to right does the tooth start big 
      (b) or small (s)?", "b");
   if (bs=="b") {
      run("Concatenate...", "  title=[Concatenated Stacks] keep 
      image1=substack3 image2=substack2 image3=substack1 image4=substack0 
      image5=[-- None --]");
   run("In [+]");
   run("In [+]");
   } 
   run("Concatenate...", "  title=[Concatenated Stacks] keep 
      image1=substack0 image2=substack1 image3=substack2 image4=substack3 
      image5=[-- None --]");
   run("In [+]");
   run("In [+]");
```

This is the code the record function gives me when I concatenate them manually...

```
   run("Concatenate...", "  title=[Concatenated Stacks] keep 
    image1=substack3 image2=substack2 image3=substack1 image4=substack0 
      image5=[-- None --]");
      run("In [+]");
      run("In [+]");
```

Whenever I input that exact code into my larger macro it tells me, ""subimage3" is not a valid choice for "image1"."